# Center Div on Side-scrolling Site Layout Horizontally and Vertically

Tags: html, layout, center, css

I am pretty new to web development. I designed a simple side-scrolling layout for a questionaire based on this very easy tutorial http://www.sitepoint.com/side-scrolling-site-layout-with-css-and-jquery/.

See the example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/emon/Rqhcf/6/

main HTML:

```
<div id="question01" class="panel">Question 1</div> 
<div id="question02" class="panel">Question 2</div> 
<div id="question03" class="panel">Question 3</div>
```

main CSS:

```
body {width: 6000px; margin: 0;}

.panel {width: 930px; float: left;  padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 1040px;
    padding-top: 45px; background: #eee;}
```

Right now, each question starts on the top-left side of the question div. However, I want to center each question inside the div horizontally (and favorably vertically as well). Additionally, the width of the question div should be dependend on the browsers viewport to center flexibly in regard to different window sizes.

This is a very frustrating problem as I don't know how to access the width of the viewport. 
Does anyone has a solution for this? And is this possible with pure html/css and cross browser?

Hoping for a solution
Norbert

Answer (score 0):

Hi i'll hope this can solve your problem chek this http://jsfiddle.net/Rqhcf/30/

To make it work is primary to work with

```
width: %
```